# HTML table row height w/ rowspan in IE

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ot9ghur0/2/) that shows the problem that I am trying to get around. It renders as I would like it to in Firefox and Chrome, but IE is taking a different approach. Basically I want the cell with contents 345 to fill in the remaining height while the rows above it are a fixed height. I've noticed that in IE if I supply a height to a cell that is **larger** than its default that it will take that height. It does not take on anything smaller than the default though.
Code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 12px; max-height: 12px">1</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="min-height: 200px; min-width: 200px; height: 200px;">1234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 12px; max-height: 12px">2</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">345</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: Removed style tag that was causing problems for FF/Chrome and updated JSFiddle link.

Comment: The jsfiddle isn't accurate. My mistake. If you remove the style tag from the bottom <td> it works correctly in Firefox/Chrome. I was experimenting in IE and didn't check to see how it affected Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: Just remove `style="height: 100%"` from 345. Does that fix it?

Comment: Not in IE. I put that in there to check to see if IE would behave the way I want it to, but it actually caused Firefox/Chrome to stop working. You're right about removing it though, it doesn't need to be there and is making things worse for FF/Chrome

Comment: Sorry I can't help you much, I don't have IE on my pc...

Comment: You might want to look into [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to handle this, but if you're using tables for E-mail templates, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: IE acts even worse when the last line which is supposed to fill in the remaining height has no content. At that point it makes that line the size of the line height and all the other rows are stretched even more.